# sftp:outbound-channel-adapter reject HostKey

Tags: spring-integration, sftp

I am trying to send the file to sftp using Spring Integration sftp outbound channel adapter.

```
<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutboundAdapter" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"channel="sftpChannel" charset="UTF-8" remote-directory="/sftp/home/sftp_foler"  remote-filename-generator-expression="'dummy.txt'"/>
```

I am getting the below error..

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to connect
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:272)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:377)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: reject HostKey: myHost
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkHost(Session.java:791)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:342)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:263)
```

I guess, I may have to set StrictHostKeyChecking to no, but how to set the value in sftp outbound gateway?
Please provide your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this one:

> Previously, the `DefaultSftpSessionFactory` unconditionally allowed connections to unknown hosts. This is now configurable (default false).
>
> The factory now requires a configured `knownHosts` file unless the `allowUnknownKeys` property is `true` (default `false`).

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/whats-new.html#_default_sftp_session_factory

Comment: Thanks Bilan for your answer. after adding the property allowUnknownKeys  as true in the DefaultSftpSessionFacory, it works like a charm!!